# Animation.startNow() or View.startAnimation()

Tags: android, android-animation

There are seemingly equivalent ways to start an animation: `Animation.startNow()` or  `View.startAnimation()`. I prefer the former, because it allows me to have more animations per view.

The problem is, that the `Animation.startNow()` method does not work. The animation just does not start. I call it from `View.onAttachedToWindow()` method:

```
@Override
 protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    myAnimation.startNow();
    invalidate();
}
```

I don't understand the difference between `start()` and `startNow()`, but neither work.

I have a custom drawn view with animated tick inside and it's user may choose, for example, scale-animate it. Both animations should run in parallel: the tick should be animated while the view still bloats.

Comment: I think you can also check the timing of when the `onAttachedToWindow()` is called. Maybe it interrupts the animation of the view or something else. :)

Comment: The animation repeats forever, so it should be visible anytime after it's started.